# Why is this code thread safe? I thought the variable testValue is updated by different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I thought the following code wasn't thread safe because variable testNum is updated by more than one threads. But I tested and saw it was thread safe. Can someone explain the difference between this code and the java code under 2?

1st code, thread safe:

```
class TestClassA() {
    @Synchronized
    fun testMethodA() {
        for (i in 0..2) {
            val testClassB = TestClassB()
            testClassB.testMethodB()
        }
    } 
}

 class TestClassB() {

    private var testNum = 0

    fun testMethodB() {
        val testThread = Thread(this::testRun)
        testThread.start()
    } 

    fun testRun() {
        testNum++
    }
}
```

2nd code, not thread safe:

```
class MyCounter {

    private static int counter = 0;

    public static int getCount() {
        return counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have two threads and one instance of `TestClassB` shared between them you will get into trouble.

Comment: A) the first snippet isn't Java B) your code is not showing any threads. C) your first example uses the Kotlin @Synchronized annotation D) how did you determine thread safety and how can you be sure that it's a correct way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, there should be a testThread.start() under this line: val testThread = Thread(this::testRun) in TestClassB.

Comment: Java with `for (i in 0..2)` and `fun testRun()`? `val`?  have i missed some update?

Comment: How do you know it's thread-safe? There is no output to show if it wasn't. --- You're creating 3 different `TestClassB` objects, so there is no object being accessed by more than one thread.

Comment: So each counter is for each TestClassB instance, and it will not be updated by other threads.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the first code is kotlin, which is similar to java.

Comment: @msProgram Use the edit link under the question to fix your question (like your comment that you forgot `thread.start()`, and anything else that you want to clarify)

Answer (score 1):

Testing can't prove that something is thread safe.  It can only prove that you got lucky and it happened to work.  Thread safety issues appear only sometimes -- in general, you *ought* to assume that thread-unsafe code will fail only when you're not looking at it and only when it would have the worst possible effects.

Neither of these is thread safe.

Comment: The first is thread safe, because there is no problem when 3 threads accessing 3 different objects. Now, if `val testClassB = TestClassB()` had been outside the loop, things would be different. --- The reason 2nd code is not thread safe is because it's a single static method, even if called using 3 different instance objects *(well-known language flaw)*.